# Installing CocoaPods on virtual machines

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, cocoapods

I am using OS X El Capitan, Version 10.11.4 using VMWare

I am able to install the gem by using `sudo gem install cocoa pods`

I want to use `Firebase` in my project and followed the guideline mentioned on official website.

On pod install, I am getting the below error

```
pod install --verbose
 Preparing

Setting up CocoaPods master repo

Cloning spec repo `master` from `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` (branch `master`)
  $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
  Cloning into 'master'...
  error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -9806
  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
  fatal: early EOF
  fatal: index-pack failed
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master`.
(/usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master

Cloning into 'master'...
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -9806
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
)
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:35:in `rescue in find_or_create_source_with_url'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:38:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:654:in `block in sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:653:in `map'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:653:in `sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:144:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:114:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:37:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:50:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

**What i have tried so far**

Went to ~/.cocoapods/repos and executed the below command

```
git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
```

And got error

```
Cloning into 'master'...
remote: Counting objects: 798955, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (26/26), done.
~/.cocoapods/repos   9% (73183/798955), 14.57 MiB | 113.00 KiB/s
```

After above line it hangs for ever, With no network activity on Activity monitor

Further, I increased the buffer size by executing

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```

Answer (score 4):

It is a connection problem.
To solve this issue, you have to go to VM settings to Bridge the physical connection.

VMware Player-->Removable Devices-->Network Adapter-->settings

You will find Network connection and check both

Bridged: Connected directly to the physical network

Replicate physical network connection state(if you are using a laptop).

Check following link for detail:

https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-826323AD-D014-475D-8909-DFA73B5A3A57.html

Answer (score 0):

It takes some time for Cloning into 'master'...  You should wait for few minutes to complete it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this particular error, but I solved similar error in either:

1. downloading the needed library through Windows operating system, then copy the library
   to **maciOS on the VMware**. (download still takes a very long time though, about a day)
2. upgrading my **RAM and get 12GB of ram and using ssd hard**. This makes it very easy to 
   develop using VMWare